# how to write unittest in Django for method with ListField variable?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I have never written a unit test before. I'm trying to write unit test for this class:

```
class User(models.Model):
    facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    friends = ListField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status_time = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    @staticmethod
    def login(cls, userid, facebook_friends):
        myuser = None
        try:
            myuser = User.objects.get(facebook_id=userid)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            myuser = User()
            myuser.status_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=16)
            myuser.facebook_id = userid
            myuser.save()

        # user exists
        myuser.friends = facebook_friends
        myuser.save()
        return {"data":myuser.get_friend_statuses()}
```

but I'm not sure how to write unit test for facebook_friend since it's in List Field class:

```
class ListField(models.TextField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
    description = "Stores a python list"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            value = []
        if isinstance(value, list):
            return value
        return ast.literal_eval(value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return unicode(value)

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
        return self.get_db_prep_value(value)
```

I tried something like this but it's not working and i'm not sure how to write it:

```
 class ListField(models.TextField):
     def test_wrong_username(self):
         user = User.login(self, 'username1', ['one', 'two', 'three'])
         errcode = User.login(self, 'username2', ['one', 'two', 'three'])
         self.assertEqual(errcode, user)
```

Can anyone help me/show me how to write the unit test for this one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to presume that instead of testing `facebook_friends` you actually want to test the login method. I'm presuming this because that is what your example test code is telling me.

Okay, so the behaviour you want from your login method is

If a user with the given userid exists it is retrieved from the database. The facebook_friends we pass into the function are saved onto the friends attribute and we return a dictionary with friends statuses.

If the user does not exist, we create it, set a couple of attributes, save it and then following the rest of the same code path as above. So, my unit test for the user exists code path of the login method might look something like this

```
import unittest
from mock import patch

class UserLoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('model.User.get_friend_statuses')
    def test_login_when_user_exists(self, mock_get_friend_statuses):
         # objects.create creates and saves a db entry in one step
         User.objects.create(facebook_id='an_id')

         return_value = User.login('an_id', ['some', 'list', 'items'])

         user = User.objects.get(facebook_id='an_id')
         self.assertEqual(user.friends, ['some', 'list', 'items'])
         self.assertEqual(
             return_value,
             {'data' mock_get_friend_statuses.return_value}
         )
         self.assertIsNone(user.status_time)
```